# ArcPy Describe function gives AttributeError?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, attributeerror

```
import arcpy
infc = r"C:\Users\123\Desktop\文件\test.shp"
print infc

desc = arcpy.Describe(infc)

print desc
shapefieldname = desc.ShapeFieldName
print shapefieldname

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(infc)
print rows
for row in rows:
    pass

appear a error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/123/Desktop/123.py", line 10, in <module>
    shapefieldname = desc.ShapeFieldName
AttributeError: DescribeData: \u65b9\u6cd5 ShapeFieldName \u4e0d\u5b58\u5728
```

Comment: try shapeFieldName instead of ShapeFieldName

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Can you please edit your question and describe what you're trying to achieve and give it a more specific title?

Comment: ? I am a rookie,but I’care it next time

Comment: Why only next time? You can edit your question...

Comment: This Question is in the "Wall of code" style, not actually containing a question. This will attract downvotes, as will the "I'll do it right next time" attitude

Comment: I‘m sorry.As a fact that I first to use StackExchange,I did't know how to change my question and I can change my question while I have asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant use the describe function to identify field names within a dataset. You have to use the [ListFields](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfields.htm) function to do this.

If you need to know the field names, use the following:

```
fields = arcpy.ListFields(infc)
for fieldnames in fields:
    print fieldnames
```

Using list comprehension, we can convert the above code into one line:

```
fields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(infc)]
```

See the [Describe](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/describe.htm) function help for more information on what properties you can access.